# Is it possible to make with CSS3 only don't using images

Tags: css, css-shapes

[image: shape]

I draw this shape  my web site , I don't know if any shape in this page can be edited to look like the shape I need.

Comment: Please have a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is about what you need, but it might need to be adjusted a little:

```css
.title{
  background-color: #000;
  height: 70px;
  line-height:70px;
  font-size:30px;
  width:200px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  margin-left: 100px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  padding-right:30px;
  position: relative;
  box-shadow: -20px -7px 0 yellow;
}
.title:after, .title:before{
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: -70px;
  top: 0;
  border-color: #000 #000 transparent transparent;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 35px;
  z-index:2;
}
.title:after{
  border-color: yellow yellow transparent transparent;
  z-index:1;
  left: -90px;
  top: -7px;
}
```

```html
<div class="title">
  Coin blanks
</div>
```